# Could someone help identify this bug?

Tags: pest-control, insect

My wife just found these bugs crawling all over a box in spare room. There were a bunch of them and they are tiny - almost invisible to the human eye. I can get some detail with my camera however.

Can anyone help me identify this bug?

[image: tiny bug]

I'm hoping it's not termites!

Comment: Doesn't look like a termite. They're mostly white and they hate the light; they'll skitter off and disappear as soon as you expose them.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, they were happily crawling around a white box in a fairly lit room

Answer (score 1):

Tracked down thanks to [Ken at BugGuide](http://bugguide.net/node/view/1087492).

It's a [booklouse](http://ento.psu.edu/extension/factsheets/booklice)

Comment: Love the BugGuide reference.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an American Oil Beetle.

http://www.insectidentification.org/beetles.asp